# Can I open blender(.blend) files created on MacOS 12.1 (M1 chip) in Windows 10?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blend-files

Can I open Blender files created on a MacOS 12.1, M1 chip Macbook Air, in windows 10?

Can I render the blender files created on the Macbook air in AWS using a windows 10 instance?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Blend files don't have any machine stuff in them.

Comment: Assuming all file paths (textures, physics cache, etc) are valid on the second computer

Comment: You could open even then. maybe render but not like result.